# Python operators precedence

Tags: python, operators

How should I interpret this sentence in Python (in terms of operators precedence)?

```
c = not a == 7 and b == 7
```

as `c = not (a == 7 and b == 7)` or `c = (not a) == 7 and b == 7`?

thanks

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Answer (score 5):

Using `dis` module:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def func():
...     c = not a == 7 and b == 7
...     
>>> dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (7)
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
              9 UNARY_NOT           
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    22
             13 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b)
             16 LOAD_CONST               1 (7)
             19 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
        >>   22 STORE_FAST               0 (c)
             25 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

So, it looks like:

```
c = (not(a == 7)) and (b == 7)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) the order is, from lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most binding):

1. `and`
2. `not`
3. `==`

So the expression `not a == 7 and b == 7` will be evaluated like this:

```
((not (a == 7)) and (b == 7))
   ^     ^       ^     ^
second first   third first
```

In other words, the evaluation tree will look like this:

```
      and
     /   \
   not   ==
    |   /  \
   ==   b  7
  /  \
  a  7
```

And the last thing done will be the assignment of the expression's value to `c`.

Comment: The link you give says that the list is ordered lowest precedence to highest precedence, so it would be `(not(a == 7)) and (b == 7)`. If it were highest to lowest, as you say, then it would be `((not a) == (7 and b)) == 7`, since `and` would be higher precedence than the `==`.

Comment: @EricFinn yup, my mistake - fixed it!