# Value in Dataframe unintentionally fulfilling If-Statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to trouble shoot why this may be happening. I am trying to go through my dataframe while skipping incomplete data. On my Dataframe the column with "Median Income" either has a numerical value or a "Unknown" or "Unavailable" in that respective row. My program will always skip the row even if the first condition isn't necessarily being fulfilled (a numerical point is provided). Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance

```
another_list = []
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Miles/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/Reservation Data.xlsx')

for all_entries in range(len(df['Median Income'])):
    variable = df.at[all_entries, 'Median Income']
    if variable == "Unknown" or 'Unavailable':
        print(f'Passed {variable}')
        pass
    else:
        print('condition')
        another_list.append([df.at[all_entries, 'Native American Population'],df.at[all_entries, 'Median Income']])

print(another_list)
```

Comment: Try to create the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't know what is in your data frame.

Comment: You have a mistake/typo in your condition, it should be: `if variable == "Unknown" or variable == "Unavailable": ...`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python operators precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009898/python-operators-precedence)

Answer (score 0):

### Simple answer

Like others stated, you have faulty `if` logic.

```
if variable == "Unknown" or "Unavailable":
```

This is equal to:

```
if (variable == "Unknown") or ("Unavailable"):
```

And the truth value of `"Unavailable"` when used in an if always evaluates to `True` (because it is a string that is not empty), so the condition is meaningless.

The correct one is of course, like mentioned,:

```
if variable == "Unknown" or variable == "Unavailable":
    ...
```

or

```
if variable in ["Unknown", "Unavailable"]:
```

### Better solution

However, you are doing this in a super complicated way.

Let's take a fictional dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Median Income": [10, 20, "Unknown", "Unavailable", 30], 
        "Native American Population": [5, 10, 2, 4, 10]
    }
)
```

To filter `"Unknown"` and `"Unavailable"` out of it, you do this:

```
filtered_df = df[~df["Median Income"].isin(["Unknown", "Unavailable"])]
```

Or in other words: from `df`, take all rows (`[]`) where it is NOT (`~`) true that `"Median income"` is either `"Unknown"` or `"Unavailable"`.